# UICollectionView header repeats every row

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm subclassing `UICollectionViewController.`

`UITableView` header repeats after every row of cells that i have.
I need the header to be "single" and always on the top of the screen (like the navigation bar).

I'm using the following code:
my `UICollectionViewController` class:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [categoryArray count] / 2;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategoryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CategoryViewModel *category = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section*2 + indexPath.row)];
    cell.name.text = category.name;
    cell.image.image = category.image;
    return cell;
}

-(UICollectionReusableView *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(headerIndexPath == nil){
        headerIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    CategoryScreenHeader *categoryScreenHeader = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:
                                         UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"CategoryScreenHeader" forIndexPath:headerIndexPath];
    categoryScreenHeader.headerName.text = @"Some title";
    categoryScreenHeader.headerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"step-0.png"];
    return categoryScreenHeader;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: i am using the UICollectionViewLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this brilliant and wonderful tutorial that works! http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView doesn't have a table header like UITableView has (to the best of my knowledge), only section headers that scroll with the content.

If you want a view at the top of the screen that stays there, then you should add 2 subviews to your controller's view, one for your header and one for the collection view. Insert the collection view into that bottom subview instead of into the controller's main view. Delete the code you have in collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: (unless you want section headers as well).